# Batch UPDATES sleep(10)

Tags: mysql

Im writing an update statement that affects a number of rows in one table on my database.

To accomplish this, I want to break that up into manageable chunks.

Initially, I thought using CONCAT would help,
`SELECT CONCAT("UPDATE table SET foo=bar WHERE ID=", id, ";") FROM`

I want to batch all these up, otherwise there will potentially cause replication lag. Preferably with do sleep(10); in between each batch

How can I accomplish this? How can I do sleep (10) between queries?

My queries right now look like this:

```
UPDATE table SET created_at = NOW() WHERE id IN (?,?,?...);
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved

Adding `DO SLEEP(10)` before each `UPDATE` is what I needed

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: ??? there is no `DO` statement in MySQL... do you mean `WHILE .. DO`?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I do sleep (10) between queries?

Simply add `SELECT SLEEP(10);` between your queries.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_sleep